# Grep between delimiters?

Tags: grep

I want to grep a text file to return only lines that contain a string found between delimiters. Is it possible to grep between delimiters?

Text looks like this:

```
Hello;Goodbye;100;200;
Hello;Goodbye;200;100;
Hello;Goodbye;300;400;
Hello;Goodbye;400;300;
```

I want to grep between the last delimiter - for example, I want to grep for '200' but only in the last column, so it returns only:

> Hello;Goodbye;100;200;

Is this possible? Thanks for any help!
S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grep supports various regular expressions. In its default mode `$` matches the end of a line.

```
grep ';200;$' test.txt
```

See [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-grep-regular-expressions-to-search-for-text-patterns-in-linux) for more advanced patterns you can do with grep.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not bound to grep, you can use eg. AWK, with that you can have more sophisticated filtering. For your question this filter out the lines you want

```
awk -F';' '$4=="200" {print}' filename
```

- -F';' defines the delimiter
- $4 defines the column number
- {print} prints out the whole line